# Passport js redirects not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, passport.js

Okay so I have implemented passportjs EXACTLY like my other projects which work perfectly, but for some reason in my current project I just cant get it to success/failure redirect.

Here's my code

**route**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/#1',
        failureRedirect: '/#2',
        failureFlash: true
    }));


app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('login', {failureRedirect: '/login'}),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log("logged");
        res.redirect('/#1');
    });
```

^ I tried it two different ways,in the second way, the 'logged' did not get logged..

**Passport**

```
//SIGN IN
    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({'username': username}, function (err, user) {
                console.log("found: " + user);
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Username not in DB'));
                }
                if (!user.checkPass(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Incorrect Password'));
                }

                //return user if all of the above pass
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }));
```

EDIT: the passport code does work well, meaning it goes right towards the end and I can console.log the correct user.